# HTML Range Construction Issue

Tags: typescript, dom, electron, range

Using `CaretPositionFromPoint` function : ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/caretPositionFromPoint )

```
let range = document.caretPositionFromPoint(selectionRectX, selectionRectY)
```

SelectionRectX = params.x, and selectionRectY = params.y are the coordinates of an angle of a rectangle got by Electron BrowserView 's `context-menu` :
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-context-menu

```
BrowserView.webContents.on('context-menu', (e, params) => {
```

Output of `params` :

```
{
    "x": 782,
    "y": 419,
    "selectionText": "than",
        "web_view_bounds": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 70,
        "width": 1850,
        "height": 1016
},
```

I get this error :

```
TS2339: Property 'caretPositionFromPoint' does not exist on type 'Document'
```

Error, for which it was already opened a bug report for TypeScript :
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49931
and it seems at the moment stuck

If I use `caretRangeFromPoint` function : ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/caretRangeFromPoint )

```
let range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(selectionRectX, selectionRectY)
```

I get this range:

[image]

which is collapsed

How to build a not-collapsed (`range.collapsed ==== false`) range from the output of the BrowserView's context-menu ?